# Need one application which is more apt for my clustering algorithms

Tags: web-services, cluster-analysis

As a part of my MTP, I exposed clustering algorithms like kmeans clustering alogrithm, pairwise clustering algorithm, etc. as web services. Now I have to find a real life application to interpret my results which I got from clustering algorithms. These clustering algorithms take datapoints (each data point represents a point in xy plane) and cluster these data points using euclidean distance. Please help me with the application which is more apt for my algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you need inside of [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org). If not, you might find people on the user list who could give you some more advice. Uncommons-watchmaker has some visualization tools, but they are not web-based.